# OpenCV OMR Sheet - Detect Marked Answers in Python - Getting Proper Binarization

Tags: opencv, image-processing, omr

While solving an OMR problem I am not completely able to detect all the marked answers correctly.
Here is my input sheet.
[Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwTq0.jpg)

my code to Binarize the image.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('input.png')
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(5,5),0)
res, img = cv2.threshold(img, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img = 255 - img
cv2.imwrite('output.png',img)
```

Result I am getting.
[Output generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPjm2.png)

I have changed the gaussian blur and threshold parameters as follow.

```
 img = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(7,7),0)  
 res, img = cv2.threshold(img, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

The result I am getting after this change.
[Result after changing Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qozlm.png)

My Desired result should look something like this.
[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7iUE.png)

Here is my complete code to detect the answers.

```
def solve(img,n_row = 50):
    height, width, channels = img.shape
    n_col = 4
    xShift = int(width/n_col)
    yShift = int(height/n_row)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (n_col * xShift, n_row*yShift))
    img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
    res, img = cv2.threshold(img, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    img = 255 - img
    for row in range(0, n_row):
        tmp_img = img [row*yShift + 5:(row+1)*yShift - 5,]
        area_sum = []
        for col in range(n_col):
            area_sum.append(np.sum(tmp_img[1:,col*xShift :(col+1)*xShift]))                
        y = str(area_sum > np.median(area_sum) * 1)
        result.append(area_sum > np.median(area_sum) * 5)
```

Please If anyone can help me solving this problem I will be super thankful.

Answer Suggestions:
How can I Check out the white pixel count inside each bounding rectangle and keep only those bounding rectangles/contours whose area is above a minimum value.

```
inputImg= cv2.imread('input.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(inputImg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype=img.dtype)
ret, otsu_threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)     
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(otsu_threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if cv2.contourArea(c) > 1500:
        cv2.rectangle(otsu_threshold, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0), 2)
cv2.imshow('Otsu', otsu_threshold)         
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: After thresholding, get contours for the marked answers. Then redraw them as filled circles of the diameter of the underlying circles at the centers determined by the image moments centroids of the contours.

Comment: A possible processing chain could be this: Convert your `BGR` image to `grayscale`. Apply `Otsu's thresholding`. Search for `external contours`. For each `external contour` get the `bounding rectangle`. Check out the _white pixel count_ inside each `bounding rectangle`. Keep only those bounding rectangles/contours whose area is above a minimum value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Threshold on color
- Apply morphology to fill out the circles
- Get external contours
- For each contour, get the centroids and draw filled circles of radius=20 on the input at the centroid locations
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('omr_sheet.jpg')
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# trim 15 from bottom to remove partial answer
img = img[0:h-15, 0:w]

# threshold on color
lower=(120,60,80)
upper=(160,100,120)
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# apply morphology close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (15,15))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# get contours
result = img.copy() 
centers = []
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
print("count:", len(contours))
print('')
i = 1
for cntr in contours:
    M = cv2.moments(cntr)
    cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    centers.append((cx,cy))
    cv2.circle(result, (cx, cy), 20, (0, 255, 0), -1)
    pt = (cx,cy)
    print("circle #:",i, "center:",pt)
    i = i + 1
    
# print list of centers
#print(centers)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('omr_sheet_thresh.png',thresh)
cv2.imwrite('omr_sheet_morph.png',morph)
cv2.imwrite('omr_sheet_result.png',result)
# show results
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("result", result)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold Image:

[image]

Morphology Image:

[image]

Results:

[image]

Answers:

```
count: 48

circle #: 1 center: (77, 3151)
circle #: 2 center: (78, 3087)
circle #: 3 center: (77, 3021)
circle #: 4 center: (76, 2959)
circle #: 5 center: (79, 2892)
circle #: 6 center: (77, 2830)
circle #: 7 center: (77, 2762)
circle #: 8 center: (78, 2695)
circle #: 9 center: (77, 2631)
circle #: 10 center: (76, 2566)
circle #: 11 center: (78, 2500)
circle #: 12 center: (77, 2435)
circle #: 13 center: (77, 2373)
circle #: 14 center: (77, 2301)
circle #: 15 center: (79, 2238)
circle #: 16 center: (79, 2178)
circle #: 17 center: (77, 2108)
circle #: 18 center: (78, 2045)
circle #: 19 center: (80, 1980)
circle #: 20 center: (78, 1913)
circle #: 21 center: (78, 1848)
circle #: 22 center: (80, 1786)
circle #: 23 center: (77, 1722)
circle #: 24 center: (77, 1657)
circle #: 25 center: (79, 1593)
circle #: 26 center: (79, 1524)
circle #: 27 center: (80, 1461)
circle #: 28 center: (77, 1395)
circle #: 29 center: (79, 1332)
circle #: 30 center: (76, 1265)
circle #: 31 center: (80, 1203)
circle #: 32 center: (73, 1136)
circle #: 33 center: (77, 1072)
circle #: 34 center: (80, 1007)
circle #: 35 center: (77, 944)
circle #: 36 center: (78, 878)
circle #: 37 center: (75, 815)
circle #: 38 center: (77, 747)
circle #: 39 center: (77, 684)
circle #: 40 center: (79, 618)
circle #: 41 center: (77, 554)
circle #: 42 center: (78, 488)
circle #: 43 center: (80, 423)
circle #: 44 center: (78, 359)
circle #: 45 center: (77, 293)
circle #: 46 center: (78, 232)
circle #: 47 center: (77, 165)
circle #: 48 center: (78, 102)
```

**ADDITION:**

This solution is probably less sensitive to color of ink.  Just threshold on white using cv2.inRange() then invert.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('omr_sheet.jpg')
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# trim 15 from bottom and 5 from right to remove partial answer and extraneous red
img = img[0:h-15, 0:w-5]

# threshold on white color
lower=(225,225,225)
upper=(255,255,255)
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
thresh = 255 - thresh

# apply morphology close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (15,15))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get contours
result = img.copy() 
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
print("count:", len(contours))
print('')
i = 1
for cntr in contours:
    M = cv2.moments(cntr)
    cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    cv2.circle(result, (cx, cy), 20, (0, 255, 0), -1)
    pt = (cx,cy)
    print("circle #:",i, "center:",pt)
    i = i + 1
    
# save results
cv2.imwrite('omr_sheet_thresh2.png',thresh)
cv2.imwrite('omr_sheet_morph2.png',morph)
cv2.imwrite('omr_sheet_result2.png',result)

# show results
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("result", result)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold Image:

[image]

Morphology Image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Centers:

```
count: 48

circle #: 1 center: (78, 3150)
circle #: 2 center: (77, 3087)
circle #: 3 center: (78, 3020)
circle #: 4 center: (77, 2959)
circle #: 5 center: (78, 2892)
circle #: 6 center: (77, 2826)
circle #: 7 center: (77, 2760)
circle #: 8 center: (78, 2694)
circle #: 9 center: (79, 2630)
circle #: 10 center: (78, 2567)
circle #: 11 center: (78, 2501)
circle #: 12 center: (77, 2435)
circle #: 13 center: (75, 2373)
circle #: 14 center: (78, 2310)
circle #: 15 center: (78, 2240)
circle #: 16 center: (77, 2176)
circle #: 17 center: (78, 2106)
circle #: 18 center: (77, 2042)
circle #: 19 center: (79, 1979)
circle #: 20 center: (78, 1912)
circle #: 21 center: (78, 1848)
circle #: 22 center: (79, 1785)
circle #: 23 center: (78, 1722)
circle #: 24 center: (78, 1656)
circle #: 25 center: (78, 1589)
circle #: 26 center: (78, 1525)
circle #: 27 center: (79, 1458)
circle #: 28 center: (78, 1396)
circle #: 29 center: (78, 1328)
circle #: 30 center: (77, 1264)
circle #: 31 center: (78, 1201)
circle #: 32 center: (76, 1135)
circle #: 33 center: (78, 1071)
circle #: 34 center: (78, 1006)
circle #: 35 center: (77, 944)
circle #: 36 center: (77, 878)
circle #: 37 center: (77, 814)
circle #: 38 center: (77, 746)
circle #: 39 center: (78, 683)
circle #: 40 center: (77, 618)
circle #: 41 center: (77, 553)
circle #: 42 center: (78, 488)
circle #: 43 center: (78, 423)
circle #: 44 center: (77, 359)
circle #: 45 center: (76, 293)
circle #: 46 center: (79, 232)
circle #: 47 center: (75, 165)
circle #: 48 center: (79, 101)
```

Comment: Sir a huge respect for you. you are my hero since the beginning I start tackling this problem. Hats Off to you!!

Comment: Just one thing how to go if the marked color is black?  how can I change the threshold range?

Comment: Edit the lower  BGR color values to include black (0,0,0) or some near black or dark gray range.  I used cv2.inRange() so that it was easy to edit and to avoid the red print. As long as the user does not fill out the forms in red ink, this should work reasonably well. The other way would be to threshold once on red and once on white and combine the two threshold images. That way any color could be used (blue or black ink) other than red ink.

Comment: You could also threshold using cv2.inRange() in HSV or LAB color space. Those might be better than in BGR.

Comment: See ADDITION in my answer for a better method of thresholding (on white) to permit more variety in the pencil/pen colors that can be used (including black/blue/green/red).

Answer (score 2):

**Analysis:**

The marked bubbles are in blue ink, which is a dominant color in the B-channel of the corresponding LAB color space.

- The B-channel captures blue and yellow colors in an image
- While A-channel captured red and green colors
- The L-channel highlights the brightness content in the image

To know more about LAB space [go through this page](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-CIELAB-color-space-diagram-The-CIELAB-or-CIE-L-a-b-color-system-represents_fig1_338303610)

**Code:**

The following snippet shows how it is useful here:

```
img = cv2.imread('omr.jpg')

# convert to LAB space
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
# store B-channel
b_channel = lab[:,:,2]
```

Notice how distinct the shaded bubbles are below:

[image]

```
# Otsu threshold on B-channel
th = cv2.threshold(b_channel,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# morphological operations to close up the gaps within
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(th, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations = 2)
```

[image]

```
# finding contours and drawing those above certain area onto black screen
contours, h = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

black = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3), np.uint8)
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 100:
        black = cv2.drawContours(black, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), -1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, it splits binary image into cells

[image: splits into cells]

and compares to find which cell has most while pixels in the row

https://dontrepeatyourself.org/post/bubble-sheet-multiple-choice-test-with-opencv-and-python/

but you must change the code follow your quiz form